# Multiple unauthorized connections to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, security

I just had a quick look into my MySQL Servers logfiles.

There I found the same entry repeated 30 to 40 times, it all happened within one minute.

It's the following:

```
<TIMESTAMP> | <THREAD> | Connect | root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX on
              <THREAD> | Connect | Access denied for user 'root'@'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (using password: YES)
```

(XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is an actual IP address, I just didn't want to show it.. But I looked it up, it's a Chinese IP from Guangzhou)

So my question is: Should I be worried or is this just a "normal" try to find a security lack on my server?

Comment: Why is your MySQL server reachable via the internet? That's nearly never a good idea.

Comment: I use it with some software I developped myself. It's nothing commercial nor do I have any sensitive data in my databases (yet..)

Comment: The MySQL server should still not be accessible from the internet. In case of the popular Webserver/MySQL stack, you usually don't bind the SQL server to the network and allow only for local networking - accessing the database from the outside will work with SSH port forwarding, which is much more secure.

Comment: As other people have pointed out, They [TM] find you very quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both...  It's normal for things to scan the interwebz looking for easy, wide-open targets.  Unfortunately for you, you seem to fall into that category.

1. Move off the default port.  Just this alone is simple enough to confuse a lot of bots.
2. Use a firewall.
3. If this is a Linux server, get something like Fail2Ban set up.
4. Configure the access permissions within MySQL to only allow known IPs to connect.  If that's not possible, try to create a VPN tunnel with the server.